# create ttf from images and script

Tags: fonts

Does any one knows software can create true-type font(ttf) from existed images and a script?

Script may look like that:

```
[aA]:./a.png
[bB]:font/b.tga
[花]:chinese/flower.png
```

**I have images already**, and I know each word of them. So I just need a tool(GUI or CLI) can export ttf file by **parsing script and put images(no matter those images represented correct words) into ttf file**.

So, anybody has any idea?

Comment: Did you found sny solution? I am in a situation of facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because .ttf is a vectorized graphics format (similar to flash, but with more precision) there's no meaningful conversion between raster graphics and .ttf.

Maybe you want to make a bitmap font instead?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts

Comment: I found some tools of making true-type fonts. Indeed, those tool usually asks me to **'draw'** font.

I'm not an artist. So I think your point is **artists should draw those font** with gimp or photoshop(I don't know does it has this function) and **export ttf for me**. Isn't it?